# Create adjacency list from relational data base table

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query, adjacency-list

I have a table like this

```
name  |  time
a     |  1:00
b     |  1:05
a     |  1:10
c     |  1:15
d     |  1:20
b     |  1:29
e     |  1:30
a     |  1:31
f     |  1:36
```

Now i get every time and want to get class sequence 5 minutes above and below.

```
a  : a->b
b  : a->b->c
a  : b->a->c
c  : a->c->d
d  : c->d
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

and I to want store those sequence in a adjacency list. Like below table

```
parent_name | child_name | graph id
  a         |   b        |    1
  a         |   b        |    2
  b         |   c        |    2
  b         |   a        |    3
  a         |   c        |    3
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do that using SQL queries?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I use oracle DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the nested set model. It is documented on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). The implementation and examples are generic, and work all SQL compliant engines, but in Oracle you can tweak it so you can benefit from the CONNECT BY clause in the SELECT statement.